Is Automated UI testing on watchOS
Can we use Appium Inspector for connecting WatchOs simulator from Xcode
I have tried it Iphone devices it worked so i want to know whether it will work for watchOs also.I'm trying to run automation test on WatchOs for that i need ui element addresses so i'm using appium inspector to get that.
